# Plotting inside a for loop in Python

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have a code that solves some time dependent equations using a for loop, where each iteration advances forward in time. I would like to plot at the end of each iteration to the same graph but I don't want to keep the old graphs once the new one is there, and I would like to see how the graph changes - not just jump to the end. It should be something like a movie of how the results change. It is something like this:

```
for k in range (0,100,1):

   #solve the equations

   #plot graph (x,y)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: To format the table/code/error correctly, please add **4 leading** space to each line of the table. Thanks!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a programming service but to answer concrete single questions for which you should show your own effort to solve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [matplotlib examples](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/animation/basic_example.html):

```
"""
=========================
Simple animation examples
=========================

This example contains two animations. The first is a random walk plot. The
second is an image animation.
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def update_line(num, data, line):
    line.set_data(data[..., :num])
    return line,

fig1 = plt.figure()

data = np.random.rand(2, 25)
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.title('test')
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, 25, fargs=(data, l),
                                   interval=50, blit=True)

# To save the animation, use the command: line_ani.save('lines.mp4')

fig2 = plt.figure()

x = np.arange(-9, 10)
y = np.arange(-9, 10).reshape(-1, 1)
base = np.hypot(x, y)
ims = []
for add in np.arange(15):
    ims.append((plt.pcolor(x, y, base + add, norm=plt.Normalize(0, 30)),))

im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig2, ims, interval=50, repeat_delay=3000,
                                   blit=True)
# To save this second animation with some metadata, use the following command:
# im_ani.save('im.mp4', metadata={'artist':'Guido'})

plt.show()
```